# Can infinite first-order categories be specified other than as categories of models?

Tags: ct.category-theory, model-theory, lo.logic

I am glad to see that a general question like [Is there a relationship between model theory and category theory?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11974/is-there-a-relationship-between-model-theory-and-category-theory) receives quite a lot attention and no down-votes for being too general and unspecific. So I feel encouraged to pose some follow-up questions (firstly restricted to first-order model theory).

#### Preliminaries

I hope the following statements are sufficiently sensible, precise and correct.

- Each first-order theory $T$ with signature $\sigma$ unambigously defines a class of (ZF-)models.
- This class of models of $T$ together with the $\sigma$-homomorphisms form a category (the *category of models of $T$*).
- Two first-order theories with two arbitrary signatures may define [equivalent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_categories) categories of models.

> **Definition**: A first-order theory $T$
> *provides a model of a category $C$* if the
> category of models of $T$ is
> equivalent to $C$.

- Each category $C$ defines a (possibly empty) set of first-order theories: the set of all $T$ which provide a model of $C$.

#### Questions

*[Remark: I had to work this question over, since it seemed to be ill-posed.]*

Old version:
Can infinite [concrete categories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_category) be specified
other than as categories of (ZF-)models of some (possibly higher-order) theory? Examples?

New version (explicitly restricted to first-order theories):

> Given an infinite category of models
> of a first-order theory $T$. Can this
> category - or one equivalent to it - be
> specified/represented/given
> independently of any first-order
> theory $T$ and its (ZF-)models?

Remark: $T$ of course *can* be specified/represented/given independently of its models: as a set of formulas.

---

> Why is the notion of *models of a (concrete)
> category* so uncommon? (Maybe because the
> answer to the first question is "No"?)

---

> Is there a genuine model-theoretic notion of two
> equivalent theories if these have
> two arbitrary signatures?

---

Comment: I don't understand the conditions of your question. How would you axiomatize, say, the category of compact Hausdorff spaces and proper maps between them? Please be a bit more specific about the language of your theories. What does "higher-order theory" refer to precisely?

Comment: I agree. The question you're asking is not the question that you want to know the answer to.  Your question is ill-defined.  However, as asked, both Charles and I gave examples, but after Charles's answer, you changed your question, which is really one of those things that's against the rules.

Comment: What you should really do is accept Charles's trivial but correct answer to your question.  Then you should look up some terminology to make sure you're being precise, because even now, my answer is still the correct answer to your question.  

Comment: Hans, it's not right to keep changing your question after it's already been answered.  Either accept Charles's answer, my answer, or I'm going to flag this post for abuse.

Comment: I just tried to *correct* my question and make it well-posed after you convinced me that it was ill-posed, not to *change* it to another question. And I commented the change to make it traceable. Anyway, I'm going to accept Charles' answer...

Comment: The policy on MO is if somebody comes up with a counterexample because you forgot to put something in your assumptions, then you are somewhat obliged to accept that answer.  It's not like we could have assumed you meant infinite.  It's not like somebody jumped out and said, "ah, yes, the 0 ring, of course".  

Comment: OK, so the policy on MO is to post a new question? Absolutely no way to *correct* a question? Is there a mode for begging for help to get a well-defined question if one doesn't know by one-self?

Comment: The issue with changing a question is that it makes things complex for people who have either answered, or have figured out how answer the old question, and makes the existing answers confusing for people who come to the question later.  Making a new question is easier, and there is no real reason not to ask them: they do not weigh much, after all.

Comment: I cordially invite you all to my question at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/13155, which seems related to this question.

Comment: @Hans. I think that unfortunately Harry is right here. If you find that your question has an "unintended" answer then the best thing to do is accept it, indicate in the comments why you don't really like that answer, ask a new question, and ideally include links between the new and old questions explaining what's happened. Essentially, we've decided that changing a question in a way that invalidates a previously good answer is inappropriate. I realise it's a bit annoying, but questions which have been changed in this way are disasters, and useless to later readers.

Comment: "Somewhat obliged" is probably a bit strong. Remember that the primary purpose of accepting an answer is for the benefit of people who want to know the right answer to the question, not out of some obligation to the poster. You can edit questions after writing for a good reason, and you shouldn't feel that you can't. But there have been problematic occasions where posters have changed their questions many times, beyond recognizability, which is really what we would like to avoid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, by direct construction.  Rings, preorders, the category of paths of a given graph, etc.  But that's not what you wanted to know, is it?

Comment: I forgot to specify that I'm interested only in infinite categories. Those direct constructions must rely on some underlying set then, don't they? (How to define an infinite preorder without some "concrete" underlying set?)

Comment: +1 for the correct answer before the op changed the question.

Comment: +1 for the correct answer before I changed the question. (Can there be direct constructions of infinite categories?)

Answer (score 5):

As for the OP's last question, "Is there a genuine model-theoretic notion of two equivalent theories if these have two arbitrary signatures:"

Sure, it's called bi-interpretability.  See pp. 1378-1379 of [this article](http://www.ams.org/notices/200011/fea-pillay.pdf) for a definition of what this means for structures.  For theories, we say that T_2 is interpretable in T_1 if there is a family of interpretation formulas (as in the linked definition) such that for *any* model M of T_1, these formulas define an interpretation in M of some model of T_2.  Similarly, as above, we can define what it means for two theories to be bi-interpretable.

If you make the class of models of T into a category by declaring the morphisms to be the *elementary* embeddings (which seems very natural to me), then it follows directly from the definition that any two theories that are bi-interpretable (without parameters) have equivalent categories of models (via the natural "interpretation functors" which translate back and forth between the two languages).
.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm sorry, the link doesn't work. Could you please give it another try?

Comment: @John: I really would appreciate the working link, since I can find "bi-interpretability" only for models/structures and classes of them, but not for theories.

Comment: @Hans: OK, tried linking to another page.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  The category of topological spaces over the category of sets is not algebraic and therefore not a category of models over the category of sets.  It is a category fibered over the category of sets. The adjunction beteween the forgetful functor and its  left adjoint is not monadic because the left adjoint produces discrete spaces.  That is, the category of models over the monad induced by the adjunction is not equivalent to Top.

Tom Leinster's book *Higher Operads, Higher Categories* has a description of this phenomenon on page 8.  He also gives a reference to Mac Lane's categories for the working mathematician, but you can find that yourself.

Edit: To answer your <strike>third</strike> second question, the reason that you don't hear people talk about models in the way you're asking is because they're called algebras over a monad or more generally algebras over an operad.

Comment: I think he's looking at general first-order theories, but your argument that topological spaces are not an algebraic category only shows that topological spaces cannot be axiomatized as an algebraic theory (i.e., operations + equational axioms). They could still be aximatized in a richer language, except I don't understand what richer language Hans has in mind.

Comment: He asked about first order models with a signature, which are exactly varieties of algebras, all of which can be described by a monadic adjunction between the base category and the category we're looking at.

Comment: Ah yes. But also note the parenthetical remark about higher-order theories. That threw me off.

Comment: @Harry: Can you give me an advice how I could cure my question in a MO-conform way: Would it be OK to strike through the remark about higher-order theories in the first question and restrict it to "algebraic or relational categories" (corresponding to "algebraic or relational theories"), ruling out higher-order theories like topology (in the first place, as I originally intended to do)? A corresponding question for higher-order theories could follow later.

Comment: I don't know what you're asking though.  If you restrict yourself to algebraic theories, then your question is a tautology, because it follows by definition that every algebraic category is equivalent to the category of models of that theory

Comment: I want to ask, whether - let's say - the category of groups can be *specified* in an independent way, not relying directly or indirectly on the class of models of group theory. (Do I have to define "specify"? I ask this honestly.)

Comment: I think I'm somewhat out of my depth and you should ask someone else.

Comment: @HS: your question does not seem well-defined to me.  The usual way to "specify" the category of groups is to say that its objects are groups and its morphisms are homomorphisms of groups.  I would say that this does not "rely" on any model-theoretic notions whatsoever: one does not need to know any model theory in order to understand or make this definition (and probably the majority of people who work with this definition do not know or care about model theory).  It happens that you can recover this category as the category of models of a certain theory: so what?  

Comment: @Pete: Let me quote another category theorists, who says, "the arrows don't, categorically speaking, know that they are specific homomorphisms, they are just some arrows you've put on a bunch of objects". My question is: How can I put the arrows on a bunch of objects without having an "intended model" in mind? How can I by accident *recover* a category to be such-and-such without having *specified* it as such-and-such beforehand?

Comment: @HS: I'm not sure who you've quoted or in what context, but the quoted statement is not mathematically meaningful.  Yes, to define a category you don't need a preconceived notion of a structure and a homomorphism of that structure: you just need some objects, morphisms between the objects, and a composition law on compatible pairs of morphisms satisfying a few axioms.  You can certainly make up an example of such a thing that does not correspond to any obvious pre-existing "structure"...

Comment:  ...E.g., given any graph, you can build a(t least one) category in which the objects are the vertices and the morphisms are the edges. (If multiple edges run between the same vertex, you have some choice as to how to define the composition of morphisms.) But I don't understand what mathematical question you're really asking: terms like "by accident", "rely on" and "specify" are opaque to me in this context. 

Comment: I certainly can make up such an example, but only a finite one. Can you give me an infinite one?

Comment: By "by accident" I wanted to paraphrase your "it happens".

Comment: I already did.  There are infinite graphs.

Comment: My question is more or less the same as this one: How can I specify a definite infinite structure - a graph, a poset, a group, a category - without assuming its objects (nodes/vertices) to have some "inner structure" on which the arrows to be defined (edges/operations) rely on?

Comment: But you said "given an infinite graph". How can an infinite graph be given?

Comment: An explicit construction of the Rado graph relies on identifying its nodes with the the natural numbers and applying a rule to check if there is an edge between x and y.

Comment: Sorry, but "How can an infinite graph be given?" is a conversation-ender for me: I cannot interpret that question in a meaningful but nontrivial way within the context of mainstream mathematics.  If you are taking some non-standard approach, then you need to be ten times clearer and more explicit about what your assumptions are.  Also I find the style of your discourse to be puzzling: "by accident" is not a paraphrase of "it happens", and I never said "given an infinite graph" (I said similar things, but that's not what quotation marks mean.)  Maybe someone else can help you out...