# How large is the supremum of minimal $V$-heights of all first-order set theories formulated in a particular language of FOST?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals, axioms

Fix a language $\mathcal{L}$ of first-order set theory. For this question, we can assume that $\mathcal{L}$ is the language described in Chapter 1 of “An introduction to set theory” [William A. R. Weiss | October 2, 2008].

Assuming that the complexity of a formula is not restricted and every formula has a finite length, construct an infinite list $Z_{\mathcal{L}}$ of all syntactically valid statements, so that every such statement is assigned an unique natural number (i.e. enumerate all syntactically valid statements).

Consider an infinite binary sequence $s$. We can assume that any such sequence corresponds to a *set of axioms* of a particular set theory $T$: an $i$-th bit of $s$ is non-zero if and only if an $i$-th statement of $Z_{\mathcal{L}}$ is an axiom of $T$. Let $t(s)$ denote a theory encoded by $s$. (For example, there will be some $s$ such that $t(s) = \text{ZFC}$.)

Then $f(s) = \alpha+1$ if and only if there exists the smallest ordinal $\alpha$ such that $V_{\alpha} \models t(s)$; otherwise, $f(s) = 0$. For example, if $t(s)=\text{ZFC},$ then $f(s)$ is equal to the successor of the initial ordinal of the smallest worldly cardinal.

Note that the phrase “any binary sequence corresponds to a set of axioms of a particular set theory $T$” does not make any assumptions about $T$: the theory may be empty (if all bits of $s$ are zero) or inconsistent. That is, almost all sequences will not correspond to a consistent theory, but we are not interested in such sequences: for any such sequence $s$ we will have $f(s) = 0$.

The ordinal $\beta_{\mathcal{L}}$ is defined as follows: $$\beta_{\mathcal{L}}  = \sup \{ f(s) : s \in {2^\omega }\}.$$

Here “$s \in {2^\omega}$” means that we take into account *all* infinite binary sequences (subsets of $\omega$).

Question: is $\beta_{\mathcal{L}}$ a well-defined ordinal? If no, why? If yes, how large is $\beta_{\mathcal{L}}$ in the hierarchy of large cardinals?

Comment: This question could be shortened substantially: there's no need to bring $2^\omega$ into things, just define $f$ directly on the set of $\{\in\}$-theories. For that matter we don't even need $f$: say that an ordinal $\alpha$ is **fresh** iff $V_\alpha\not\equiv V_\gamma$ for any $\gamma<\alpha$, then you're asking for the supremum of the fresh ordinals (and I think this makes it easier to see that the ordinal in question is perfectly well-defined). Finally, note that your example is incorrect: "inaccessible" should be replaced by "worldly."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ordinal $\beta_\mathcal{L}$ is perfectly well-defined: in my opinion it's more easily thought of as $$\sup\{\alpha: \forall \beta<\alpha(V_\beta\not\equiv V_\alpha)\},$$ and this definition should be clearly unproblematic (note that [Tarski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_undefinability_theorem) notwithstanding there is no problem in talking about truth relative to a *set-sized* structure like the $V_\alpha$s). Moreover, this definition avoids any reference to coding of theories by reals, which adds a lot of unnecessary length to the question.

As to how big $\beta_\mathcal{L}$ is, the key observation is that levels of the cumulative hierarchy are correct about "local" phenomena. For example, $\beta_\mathcal{L}$ is greater than the least measurable cardinal $\mu$ if the latter exists, since the measurability of $\mu$ is visible in $V_{\mu+2}$. To get past $\beta_\mathcal{L}$, you need to look at large cardinal properties which more significantly reach up the cumulative hierarchy - e.g. we trivially have that $\beta_\mathcal{L}$ is less than the least **supercompact** if the latter exists.

Comment: It seems that I need an explanation for the claim that $\beta_{\mathcal{L}}$ is less than the least supercompact. Consider the theory T = ZFC + "there exists a supercompact cardinal", which corresponds to some infinite binary sequence (existence of a supercompact cardinal is $\Sigma_3$ in the Lévy hierarchy). What is the smallest ordinal $\alpha$ such that $V_{\alpha} \models \text{T}?$ Note that $\alpha$ must be much smaller than $\beta_{\mathcal{L}}.$

Comment: More precisely, $\beta_{\mathcal{L}}$ is less than or equal to the least [$\Sigma_2$-correct cardinal](http://cantorsattic.info/Reflecting_cardinals#.24.5CSigma_2.24-correct_cardinals).

Comment: @lyricallywicked If there is no cardinal that is supercompact up to the next worldly cardinal, there is no $\alpha$ such that $V_\alpha \vDash T$, even if there is a cardinal that is supercompact in $V$, for that supercompact cardinal may be the greatest worldly cardinal.

Comment: @ArvidSamuelsson: thank you for the explanation. Yes, my statement "$\alpha$ must be much smaller than $\beta_{\mathcal{L}}$" should be "$\alpha$ (if it exists) must be much smaller than $\beta_{\mathcal{L}}$"...

Comment: @lyricallywicked I think that $\alpha$ (assuming it exists) has no definition snappier than "The smallest ordinal $\alpha$ such that $V_\alpha\models T$." If you really want a different type of definition, you should specify what you're looking for (and note that it may not exist).

Comment: I have read the answers to [this question on Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15685/is-it-necessary-that-model-of-theory-is-a-set), and now I have another question: if T = ZFC + "there exists a supercompact cardinal" is consistent, does T have _a set model_?

Comment: @lyricallywicked Yes, due to the completeness theorem, and this has nothing to do with the details of $T$ here. $T$ may not have a *transitive* set model, though, let alone one of the form $V_\alpha$ for some ordinal $\alpha$.

Comment: Then if $S$ is a set that models such T, what is the _minimal_ rank of $S$?

Comment: @lyricallywicked Depending on the model $S$ it could be quite small: every computably axiomatizable consistent theory has a "not-too-incomputable" model (e.g. $<_T0'$), so in particular if $T$ is consistent then it has a model in $L_{\omega+1}$. And again, this has nothing to do with the details of $T$ (beyond its computable axiomatizability). Of course, such a model won't be well-founded, or even an $\omega$-model.

Comment: "this has nothing to do with the details of T (beyond its computable axiomatizability)" — wait, but the question of this post implies that there is _no_ such limitation. Pick _any_ consistent theory T from the set of _all_ infinite binary sequences (note that T may be _uncomputably_ axiomatizable, and the complexity of axioms is unrestricted in the Lévy hierarchy). Then T must have a set model $S$. How large can the minimal rank of $S$ be? Will the answer depend on the [definition of rank](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1685548/two-ways-of-defining-rank-of-a-set)?

Comment: @lyricallywicked I'm not sure what your objection is. In your *comment* you asked about ZFC+supercompact, so in my *comment* I focused on that. In your *question* you asked about general theories, so in my *answer* I focused on that. Which do you actually want to know about here?

Comment: "I'm not sure what your objection is." — there was no objection; I just wanted to clarify a few things that are somewhat unrelated to the answer. "Which do you actually want to know about here?" — I wanted to know about the heights of the minimal rank of set models of uncomputably axiomatizable theories (such theories are mentioned in [your comment on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4402379/minimal-models-in-strong-set-theories#comment9208905_4402407)). (Maybe this question needs a separate post.) Sorry for the possible confusion and thank you for the explanations!